# Finding the maximum curvature along the perimeter of a binary mask

Tags: python, image-processing, curve, calculus, voronoi

I am seeking a method in Python for identifying the point of maximum curvature along the curve that traces the perimeter of a polygon.

Some background: I am developing a method for finding the midlines of binary masks of carrot roots. I am using Voronoi diagrams, which work well in most cases, but occasionally, what I would visually consider to be the “tip” of the mask is not connected to the longest path of the Voronoi graph, and I get undesirable results. E.g.:

[image: Long carrot]

[image: Ball carrot]

In effect, the graph connects "prematurely" to a point along the binary mask contour that constitutes the longest path, but clearly does not conform to what I would call the "midline". I think I can address this problem by pruning the Voronoi graph back to the point where it begins to produce multiple spurs, and then simply connect this to the true “tip” of the carrot.

I think that this “tip” should be the point of maximum curvature, assuming I sufficiently smooth the masks to eliminate small side branches.

Does anyone out there know how to implement an efficient method in Python for scanning around the perimeter of these arbitrary polygons, and finding the point of maximum curvature?

Comment: If you sufficiently smooth the masks, your skeleton (or "Voronoi graph" as you call it) will not have these side spurs, and will more closely match what you expect.

Comment: The curvature of a polygon is going to be 0 except at the nodes where it would be undefined.  Does your smoothing operation involve fitting smoother function to the curve?

Comment: That's a great point Chris, I will try to pre-smooth the images and then add the lost pixels back after tracing the midlines.

Comment: You're right John, I would have to first fit splines to some region of the polygon before estimating curvature at any given point.  I have not done this yet.

Comment: Can you make the mask data available? I can think of a couple of approaches that don't involve Voronoi diagrams at all, and that I don't think will have this problem, but I would need to test them on real data.

Comment: Absolutely @senderle!  Here a bunch of relatively simple masks with no branching:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uhj0l7rx2w777ge/AAAuiNHJnVGVJRPxXpiGqZi1a?dl=0

Here are some additional masks of roots that have a more complex branching structure (I haven't figured out how to deal with these, because they of course have more than one midline.  Maybe just more severe pre-smoothing):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kpbs0tzbebottpz/AAD5trR59xkZNXog03_SVvRja?dl=0